# Having trouble with a very basic search -- no results

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, nest

I have Elasticsearch up and running.  Using Sense within Marvel, I am able to get a result, with this query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "massa"
    }
  }
}
```

My c# code, trying to recreate the above:

```
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).SetDefaultIndex("mediaitems");
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var results = client.Search<stuff>(s => s
        .Query(qs => qs.QueryString(q => q.Query("massa"))));

    var d = results.Documents;
```

But unfortunately I'm not getting any results, nothing in "results.Documents".  Any suggestions?  Maybe a way to see the generated json?  What is the simplest way to just query everything in an index?  Thanks!

Comment: You're adding specific `Field`s in your C# code, but not in the hand written version. Try removing that and check.

Comment: Sorry, yes, "Fields" was a later addition, same issue with or without fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your search results are going to be mapped to the proper type because you are using `.Search<stuff>`, you still need to set the default type as part of your query.

```cs
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).SetDefaultIndex("mediaitems");
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var results = client.Search<stuff>(s => s
        .Type("stuff") //or .Type(typeof(stuff)) if you have decorated your stuff class correctly.
        .Query(qs => qs.QueryString(q => q.Query("massa"))));

    var d = results.Documents;
```

Additionally, your `results` response contains a `ConnectionStatus` property. You can interrogate this property to see the `Request` and `Response` to/from Elasticsearch to see if your query is being executed as you expect.

**Update:** You can also set a default type the index settings as well.

```
  var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).SetDefualtIndex("mediaitems");
  settings.MapDefaultTypeIndices(d=>d.Add(typeof(stuff), "mediaitems");
```

Comment: OK, thank you.  It seems like I shouldn't need .Type("stuff"), but adding it did work, and I'm getting results.  I will need to read up on how to decorate my classes properly.

Comment: Here is the documentation on setting up NEST Mapping using either Attributes or code. http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html

Comment: .Search() will search `/{inferred_index}/{inferred_type}/_search` by default. See http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/index-type-inference.html. In your example you are only searching on `/_search` you can specify the same in NEST using `s=>s.AllIndices().AllTypes()`. Specifying `.Type("stuff")` fixates the `{inferred_index}` so the search will happen on `/{inferred_index}/stuff/_search`

Answer (score 1):

You can also check nest raw client

```
var results = client.Raw.SearchPost("mediaitems", "stuff", new
      {
          query = new
          {
              query_string = new
              {
                      query = "massa"
              }
          }
      });
```

Comment: This was useful, unfortunately I can't mark it as useful as I am too new.  But, this did return results and was able to inform what I needed to do with Paige's answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values of search request URL and JSON request body as under:

```
var requestURL = response.RequestInformation.RequestUrl;
var jsonBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestInformation.Request);
```

You can find other useful properties in `RequestInformation` for debugging.